# Как сделать Release С# приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, build

Сейчас пытаюсь сделать так:

- `dotnet build`
- `dotnet publish`

Но в обоих случаях получаю Debug сборку.

Для разработки использую Visual Studio Code.

Comment: `dotnet build --configuration Release`

Comment: @Kalmankantaja при выполнении этой команды просто создается папка с именем `Release` и в нее попадает все тот-же дебажный билд.

Comment: @NickolayChistov как вы поняли что он дебажный?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja просто как-то раз я написал команду `dotnet build --configuration --help` и просто создалась папка `--help`, хотя я хотел просто получить помощь.

Comment: А PDB файл в релизе это нормально?

Comment: @Lasna точно не знаю, я им никогда не пользовался.

Comment: @Lasna да, это нормально. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899586/17025310